# gas estimation errored with the following message - execution reverted

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.6 < 0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {

     mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;

     function fund() public payable {
         uint256 minimumUSD = 30 * 10 ** 18;
         require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH");
         addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
     }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }

    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }

    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount)/1000000000000000000;
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

I write this piece of code. I get this message every time I deploy:

"gas estimation errored with the following message - execution reverted"

I know problem is in:

```
     function fund() public payable {
         uint256 minimumUSD = 30 * 10 ** 18;
         require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH");
         addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
     }
```

In this function I try to avoid geting value below 30$.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: On which network are you deploying the contract (Ethereum mainnet, Rinkeby testnet, Remix VM emulator, ...)?